# ARToolKit marker detect java Method

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, artoolkit

I am using ARToolKit nftSimple example and trying to java method when marker is detected but code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a much easier way without touching the NDK.

The ARToolkit class has methods for querying the visibility of the markers, they are usually invoked on the Renderer, but you could as well create a thread that keeps checking them.

This is the code you need to check for marker visibility in Java:

```
boolean markerVisible = ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(mMarkerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just extended the sample arSimpleProj (the Android Studio project).

In the class `org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimple.SimpleRenderer`

after line 104 add the following:

```
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(activity,PlainActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(newActivity);
```

You need to have a Activity named PlainActivity with a corresponding layout.